# probability of selecting two roses of different colors when two roses are drawn at random from $2$ red roses, $4$ yellow roses and $6$ pink roses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

A bag contains $2$ red roses, $4$ yellow roses and $6$ pink roses. Two roses are drawn at random. What is the probability that they are not of same color?

This problem can be easily solved with $$\frac{2C1 \cdot 4C1 + 4C1 \cdot 6C1 + 6C1 \cdot 2C1}{12C2} = \frac{2}{3}$$

But I want to do this using the ratio method and here is my attempt:
RY + YP + PR =
$$\frac{2}{12} \cdot \frac{4}{12} + \frac{4}{12} \cdot \frac{6}{12} + \frac{6}{12} \cdot \frac{2}{12} = \frac{11}{36}$$
which is way off, what am I doing wrong? and also how does one decide when to use the ratio method and when to use the Combinatorics method.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It looks like the way you are counting necessitates the counting of $YR, PY,$ and $RP$ as well. This would scale the result by $2$ to $22/36$, so I am not sure about the other $2/36$ so I may be wrong.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  In particular, note that typing `\binom{n}{k}` yields $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you must also count $YR,PY$, and $RP$. Note that when you are picking the roses for $R$, once you pick a rose for $Y$, you must use $11$ in the denominator as one rose has already been picked out.

So then we have the following:

$\frac{2}{12}\cdot \frac {4}{11} + \frac{4}{12} \cdot \frac {6}{11} + \frac{6}{12} \cdot \frac{2}{11} = \frac{11}{33}$.

Then we have $2\cdot\frac{11}{33} = \frac {22}{33} = \frac{2}{3}$ after scaling by two when taking into account the other three cases listed above as the resulting value is clearly the same from the commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: oops, stupid me, forgot to exclude the rose picked. :P Now I see, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your computation using direct probabilities has two types of errors:

(a) you have forgotten that each duo can occur in two sequences.

(b) The denominator for any duo can't remain the same !

So the correct computation presented taking into account the above simply, would be

$\frac{2}{12\cdot 11}(2\cdot4 + 4\cdot 6 + 6\cdot 2) $

The two answers must necessarily tally, and you need to decide which of the two methods is easier for the particular problem. In general, direct use of probabilities is simpler only when there is a *fixed* order, else beginners tend to make errors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are absolutely right, I see it now. :) Thank You so much.

Comment: Glad to be of help !